# Creating windows emulator in Appcelerator

Tags: windows, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-studio

How to create windows emulator for windows app development in Appcelerator studio.

Answer (score 0):

They should appear automatically if you have followed:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Installing_the_Windows_Phone_SDK

Run `[appc] ti info -t windows` to see what Studio/CLI sees.